# If having many devices in the intermediate layer of Apache IoTDB data structure, how can I create a metadata template?

Tags: templates, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If I have a root name called `root.gps.phone.p18035198120.lan`, and p18035198120 represents the mobile number, how should I create a metadata template, or do I need to create a metadata template in Apache IoTDB? There will be many devices involved, and each device has a device number. I wonder do I need to create a template like `root.gps.phone.*.lan` in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of using templates in Apache IoTDB is to save memory resources used to manage metadata, so if there are many devices with the same data structure, it is recommended to use templates (which is your case).
The example template you mentioned can be created in IoTDB and the template can be mounted to any node.